# Send number (in String format) as one single byte and read it through Serial Port

Tags: c#, android, bluetooth, serial-port

I've been working on a project where an Android sends to a PIC a number, through Bluetooth, and the PIC sends the same number to my Notebook, through Serial Port.

Currently, I have **two** different applications running in this project.

- The first application runs on the Android, which basically lets the user choose a number to send by Bluetooth. For example, "123".

To send the number through Bluetooth, I use the code below:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[1];
bytes[0] = byte.Parse(<Number entered by user, in string format>);
await _socket.OutputStream.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

The byte is received by the PIC, and the same data is sent to the Serial Port.

- Now, another application, running in my Notebook (connected to the COMM3 Serial Port) receives the data, but it prints:

`Received: 75`

instead of '123'.

After that, I tried to change my code above, because I thought it could be something related to the encoding. So now my code is:

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(<Number entered by user, in string format>);
await _socket.OutputStream.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

Now, my application prints:

```
Received: 1
Received: 2
Received: 3
```

It's almost what I wanted. I need to work with the exactly same integer that the user entered in my Android Application, so it should print:

```
Received: 123
```

My bytes array is probably something like:

```
bytes[0] = b'00110001' ("1" according ASCII Table)
bytes[1] = b'00110010' ("2" according ASCII Table)
bytes[2] = b'00110011' ("3" according ASCII Table)
```

When all I need is one byte:

```
byte = b'01111011' (123 in binary)
```

Any idea on how to properly send a string and read it as only one byte?

(Considering that my string will always be a number, from 0 to 255)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without the PIC code it can be anything... have you tried to debug the PIC? check if the received number is correct and check if you send the byte as byte or as string.

Comment: Have you double checked that the bauds on the PIC are the same as the ones on your PC? and checked the PIC osc calibration?

Comment: Weird. Have you tried just setting the byte you're sending to 123? I can't think of why you'd be losing bits 5 and 6.

Comment: @Gusman The application I'm using in my Notebook was written by my professor (I don't have access to the source code), but it's using a baud rate of 9600. My pic too, because I've already used this .asm code to send the numbers "0" and "1" to control a LED.

Note that these numbers were sent manually as binary numbers, not parsed from a string as my current project.

Comment: the parsing you have done is correct, and has been done on the Android part, so I would discard that, check if the oscillator, peripheral clock divider and so on are correctly configured, as that can vary the serial port baud rate.

Comment: In the post I've used the "123" example, where it shows as "75".
I've tried to send the numbers "0" and "1", and the notebook application receives as "208" and "209" respectively (With the first code).

Comment: The first code is correct, you parse the string as a byte and then you send it, that part is ok for sure, again it seems to me some speed problem, it's the most usual cause of problems, belive me, I have suffered them :)

Comment: which model of PIC are you using?

Comment: @Gusman I'm using the PIC16F873A. My equipments are in the uni laboratory, so I don't have access to them now to test :(

Comment: well, then when you have time check these parameters, even better, if you're on a lab, then the best youcan do is to attach an oscope to the serial port and read the values, you can then very easily check the real output from the device, it's speed and the value sent.

Comment: @Gusman alright!

Thank you for the quick replies, I will probably go back to lab tomorrow.